# How to flush Firefox storage SQLite database files to eliminate large SQLITE-WAL files?

Tags: firefox, database, sql, sqlite, places.sqlite

I've noticed that the [WAL (Write Ahead Log)](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) files (*.sqlite-wal) associated with the SQLite databases (*.sqlite) used by the Firefox web browser often get quite large.  They literally can get over 150 times the size of the associated SQLite databases, and remain that size for months (years? forever?).

According to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64538469/4182398), a possible solution may be to run the following SQLite pragma command on each affected storage database:

```
PRAGMA schema.wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE);
```

In theory, one could use an SQLite tool external to Firefox to perform this action, but I've learned that performing actions *within* Firefox generally yields the best results.  *(For example, try to work with `omni.jar` outside of Firefox... it can be a PITA because Mozilla uses an atypical JAR structure.)*

Within Firefox, is there a way to flush all its SQLite storage databases so their contents are written completely within the corresponding `.sqlite` files?

---

UPDATE:

I would like to mention that one of the primary goals in posting this question is to safely deal with the `storage-sync-v2.sqlite-wal` file that grows until it reaches 32MB in each Firefox profile.  The corresponding database, `storage-sync-v2.sqlite`, also has a `storage-sync-v2.shm` file, but tends to remain rather small.  To keep things focused on **one topic per question**, I wrote a [related question to specifically address that goal](https://superuser.com/questions/1768738/optimizing-firefox-i-o-regarding-storage-sync-v2-sqlite-wal-file-storage-sync-v).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quit the Firefox instance that uses the profile that contains the databases in question.

Launch Firefox from a temporary profile. Open the Browser Console and paste the following snippet. Edit the path string so that it points to the target profile. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Repeat for every sqlite database.

Hopefully this will work like charm, but it wouldn't hurt to backup your profile before trying anything.

```js
(()=>{
  let file = new FileUtils.File("/pathToTargetProfile/places.sqlite"); // edit this string
  let db = Services.storage.openDatabase(file);
  let stmt = db.createStatement("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)");
  stmt.executeStep();
  console.log(stmt.row); //this might provide useful info
  stmt.finalize();
  db.close();
})();
```

Comment: I don't think it is wise to change settings when running firefox.  This may have unpredictable consequences.

Comment: I clearly state that the snippet must be executed from a separate profile, and no Firefox instance using the target profile should be running.

Comment: I see, you want to edit a sqlite DB from other firefox.  That is good idea, but why to do it this way and not use a addon like SQLite Manager directly from Firefox editing other Firefox profile.  This does not differ from it because the Firefox is turned off.

Comment: SQLite Manager does not use Firefox own SQLite library (the api is not available to extensions). And the OP stated that prefers to avoid third party tools.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually really good question, which not many people ask.

The `.sqlite-wal` file grows to 32MB limit as this is probably the transaction journal limit which you (or your package creator) have defined during the compile of your firefox's sqlite.

The directive with which you can adjust the transaction journal limit during compile time is called [`SQLITE_DEFAULT_JOURNAL_SIZE_LIMIT`](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#default_journal_size_limit) and it is defined in **bytes**.  In your case it is 32MB.

You also can adjust the transaction journal limit later on in the sqlite with:

[`PRAGMA schema.journal_size_limit = N ;`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_size_limit) (again **N** is in **bytes**, negative number sets no limit)

What you have to understand this is a **soft limit**, not a hard one.  If you have an active process that is writing into the journal; it will continue to write even when the specified limit is reached.  It can easily reach 2GB even when you have 20MB limit defined.

This limit is for **inactive** transaction journal.  I think the Firefox developers decided 32MB is the right balance between having a write-ahead-log and speed.

If you want to adjust the PRAGMA size after compilation you need to do it for each profile you have.  If you plan on using many profiles/database you probably want to recompile it with the `SQLITE_DEFAULT_JOURNAL_SIZE_LIMIT` set.

To quote valid sections from the man:

> In WAL mode, the write-ahead log file is not truncated following a
> checkpoint. Instead, SQLite reuses the existing file for subsequent
> WAL entries since overwriting is faster than appending.
>
> The journal_size_limit pragma may be used to limit the size of
> rollback-journal and WAL files left in the file-system after
> transactions or checkpoints. Each time a transaction is committed or a
> WAL file resets, SQLite compares the size of the rollback journal file
> or WAL file left in the file-system to the size limit set by this
> pragma and if the journal or WAL file is larger it is truncated to the
> limit.
>
> The second form of the pragma listed above is used to set a new limit
> in bytes for the specified database. A negative number implies no
> limit. To always truncate rollback journals and WAL files to their
> minimum size, set the journal_size_limit to zero. Both the first and
> second forms of the pragma listed above return a single result row
> containing a single integer column - the value of the journal size
> limit in bytes. The default journal size limit is -1 (no limit). The
> SQLITE_DEFAULT_JOURNAL_SIZE_LIMIT preprocessor macro can be used to
> change the default journal size limit at compile-time.
>
> This pragma only operates on the single database specified prior to
> the pragma name (or on the "main" database if no database is
> specified.) There is no way to change the journal size limit on all
> attached databases using a single PRAGMA statement. The size limit
> must be set separately for each attached database.

### **An update:**

I forgot to mention one important SQLite parameter  [`wal_autocheckpoint=N;`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_autocheckpoint)(where N is **number** of 32KiB **pages** in a 512KiB journal).  (Which OP already mentioned when truncating the data)

You can configure it to use smaller autocheckpoint.  Note that this affect performance of the SQLite and thus the browser.  Too many checkpoints will slow down the browser.

To correctly [configure auto-checkpoint](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/wal_autocheckpoint.html) follow the link.

What is also important to note that checkpoints initiated in such way are [**PASSIVE**](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/wal_checkpoint_v2.html).  Which means that SQLite should do as much as possible without blocking.

To quote the man for the PASSIVE mode:

> SQLITE_CHECKPOINT_PASSIVE
> Checkpoint as many frames as possible without waiting for any database readers or writers to finish, then sync the database file if
> all frames in the log were checkpointed. The busy-handler callback is
> never invoked in the SQLITE_CHECKPOINT_PASSIVE mode. On the other
> hand, passive mode might leave the checkpoint unfinished if there are
> concurrent readers or writers.

Same as above the update note you can also set this option during compile time with [`SQLITE_DEFAULT_WAL_AUTOCHECKPOINT=<pages>`](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#default_wal_autocheckpoint).

From man:

> This macro sets the default page count for the WAL automatic
> checkpointing feature. If unspecified, the default page count is 1000.

Comment: Thanks tukan.  Excellent and helpful information in your answer.  Within Firefox, is there a way to issue a SQLite PRAGMA statement to affect the desired database?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I my best knowledge no.  This is an internal settings for SQLite.  The only option outside changing it via sqlite client is to compile it with different size.  I think changing the setting for WAL should be fine.  There is also WAL2, but there I would be careful (https://sqlite.org/cgi/src/doc/wal2/doc/wal2.md) This is the WAL2 https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/timeline?r=wal2.

Comment: I've never been so torn as to which answer to award a bounty.  I wish Stack Exchange allowed me to award the bounty 50% to your answer and 50% to the answer by 'paa'.  After much thought, I've gone with the answer provided by 'paa' only because it directly provides an exact answer to the question asked.  But your answer is so filled with tremendously useful information, I want to take a special moment out of my life to thank you for posting it.  I sincerely appreciate it! (And, of course, I upvoted it to provide a small award too!)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket you are right to give him the bounty.  I gave him upvote too as he answered your question, but I still think it is not a good solution to the problem at hand as you will hardly do that very often.  It is much better to have reasonable, measured data of your environment and compile your firefox with the proper configuration.