# Optimizing Firefox I/O regarding storage-sync-v2.sqlite-wal file (storage-sync-v2.sqlite database write ahead log file)

Tags: firefox, performance, sync, database, sqlite

In my experience, Firefox creates a `storage-sync-v2.sqlite` database in each of its profile folders.  This appears to happen even if profile syncing is disabled (and has never been enabled).

What's odd (and perhaps a bug) is that Firefox also creates a `storage-sync-v2.sqlite-wal` file in each profile folder that will continually grow until it reaches 32MB in size.  A `SQLITE-WAL` file is a Write Ahead Log (WAL) file for SQLite databases.  This typically makes that file the largest file within the Firefox profile folder hierarchy. The corresponding database, `storage-sync-v2.sqlite`, also has a `storage-sync-v2.shm` file, but it tends to remain rather small.

On devices with limited I/O bandwidth, limited storage, and limited number of total read/write operations available on the storage medium (MTBF), such extraneous I/O is undesirable.

Is there a way to prevent Firefox from creating the `storage-sync-v2.sqlite` database in each of its profile folders, or at least preventing Firefox from allowing the `storage-sync-v2.sqlite-wal` to reach such a large size?

Related question:
[How to flush Firefox storage SQLite database files to eliminate large SQLITE-WAL files?](https://superuser.com/questions/1767782/how-to-flush-firefox-storage-sqlite-database-files-to-eliminate-large-sqlite-wal)